# Concisely "update" the for-loop iterators of a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I want to start a loop with an initial number of iterators, but that this number updates if something happened in the loop. The language is python. For example, I had a dataframe with "n" rows, I want to loop between all the rows of the dataframe. But in the loop I appened "y" rows, and now I want to add this "y" rows to the iteration.

I had this toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

i = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row["A"])
    if(i<2):
        df.loc[len(df),"A"] = max(df["A"]) + 1
    else:
        pass
    # End if
    i += 1
# End for
```

what I expect in the output is:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
```

What I get:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

I can get the expected result using a while-loop outside the for-loop, but I think it is not a concise solution.

Code for the while-loop solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4], "B": [1, 1, 1, 1]})

i = 0
condition = True # Added to stop the while loop
while(condition):
    aux_df = df[df["B"] == 1] # Only iterate btw "new" rows
    for index, row in aux_df.iterrows():
        print(index, row["A"], row["B"]) # row["B"] added to check
        if(i<2):
            last_len = len(df1)
            df.loc[last_len, "A"] = max(df["A"]) + 1
            df.loc[last_len, "B"] = 1 # Added to iterate in the next round
        else:
            pass
        # End if
        df.loc[index, "B"] = 0 # Updated to not iterate in the next round
        i += 1
    # End for
    
    # Added to check whether or not I have to continue with the loop.
    if(df["B"].sum()>0):
        pass
    else:
        condition = False
    # End if
# End while
```

Comment: The desired output of the first code is actually the expected output.

Comment: your first block of code ends with `df` try `print(df)` to see your result

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. The last line printing the df was superfluous. The output corresponds to the impressions inside the loop. I just edited the question

Comment: Note as well the warning in the docs about `interrows()` "*You should **never modify** something you are iterating over*"

Comment: Than you, both, @mozway and @JonSG, for your answers. @JonSG, I think that that warning refers to: if some element in row is modified (for example, `row["A"] = 2`) and you expect that change to be reflected in `df[index, "A"]`.

Comment: In general you should never need to use `iterrows`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `interrows()` documentations specifically warns:

> "You should never modify something you are iterating over"

That is likely because people like to try to delete while iterating which is a bad thing.

I would start by switching to a while loop and test against the length of the dataframe:

maybe something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

index = 0
while index < len(df.index):
    print(index, int(df.iloc[index]["A"]))
    if index < 2:
        df.loc[len(df),"A"] = max(df["A"]) + 1
    index += 1
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, this solution works fine and is more concise than the one I found.